# Loading a HTML page without waiting for certain parts to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, loading

I have a simple HTML page which contains many parts, out of which one part

`<div id="external_data">...</div>`

renders data from an external source and loads. It takes a very long time to load, and thus all the other parts of the page also wait till this section is loaded.

Is there way using jQuery or something else, to set the content of `<div id="external_data">` to a `loading image` and load the rest of the page without depending on that one section ? and How do I achieve this?

Comment: yes, there is a way to do that with jQuery, thanks for asking.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your javascript code? How is that external code loaded?

Comment: Okay. That's good to know. How, Any resources please? I haven't tried anything, as I do not know where to start. The external data is populated into the HTML from the backend script.

Comment: @user2354302 We aren't here to do your research for you. Research and try to solve it yourself. When you have a real problem that you can reproduce using a relatively small piece of code, THEN come to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content of that div is rendered server-side and served with the rest of the page, there's two options you could go for:

1) Serve the page with the div containing the loading graphic you mentioned, and then use jQuery to load the contents of the div with a $.post or $.get when the page loads. This will allow the page to be served without whatever back-end logic you have holding up everything else.

2) If you don't like using $.post or $.get, you can put an iFrame in that div that references another page which has the div contents. This will load separately from the page, thus not holding things up. However, be advised that iFrames sometimes behave strangely between browsers in terms of sizing, borders, etc. Make sure your code is tested in all major browsers (mainly IE) to make sure it looks ok in all of them.